# Как дополнять json файл?

Tags: python, json

Код работает без ошибок, новые данные записываются, но удаляются. Возможно это не из-за json, а из-за словаря

```
import json
import time


class expenses:
    def __init__(self, account_of_lost, amount_of_loss):
        self.id_spisania = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
        self.account_of_lost = account_of_lost
        self.data_of_lost = time.strftime("%d %b %Y")
        self.amount_of_loss = amount_of_loss

    def add_new_expenses(self):
        spisania_dict = {}

        spisania_dict[self.id_spisania] = {
            "data": self.data_of_lost,
            "summa": self.amount_of_loss,
            "schet": self.account_of_lost,
            "valuta": "TRY",
        }

        with open("dict.json", "r+") as file:
            json.dump(spisania_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


exns = expenses("Наличка", 100)


def main():
    user_choise = input("Хотите продолжить?")

    while user_choise == "да":
        exns.add_new_expenses()
        user_choise = input("Хотите продолжить?")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Если вам нужна сделать дозапись в файл, то используйте **open('file.txt', 'a')**

Comment: Тут запись в json, а не txt..

Comment: с фалом **a** тоже не идёт дозапись ?

Comment: нет, там все новые данные просто на друг друга налезли.

Comment: Так вы же очищаете каждый раз список операций при вызове `add_new_expenses`: `spisania_dict = {}` и записываете в файл только список с последней операцией

Answer (score 3):

Дописать в `JSON` можно, но как правило эта задача решается костыльно и ничего такого универсального, что можно применять на практике я не нашел. И в любом случае функции поиска нужного ключа по файлу не отличаются быстродействием, а уж перезапись определенной строки может ломать форматирование если не учитывать нечитаемые символы, кодировку и проч. Все вышесказанное приводит к нестабильности и хрупкости рабочего процесса.

Логика для работы без костылей может быть такой:

1. Прочитать из `json` в словарь/список полностью
2. Работать с данным словарем/списком, как с целой сущностью
3. Перезаписать файл полностью, после того как словарь/список будет заполнен/дополнен/обновлен и так далее.

Не очень хорошее решения для больших файлов, но мой аргумент такой, если json файл настолько велик, что с ним сложно работать => надо использовать базу данных.

Относительно вашего кода. Я бы сохранение вынес в отдельную функцию (одна ответственность) после накопления всех сущностей в директиве `while`, а далее вызывал функцию сохранения.